# Manipular caminho de um input de formulário enviado para url

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, input

Estou testando um campo de pesquisa que envia o que o usuário digita diretamente para o site que escolhi (em uma nova aba), pesquisando no próprio site, e funciona perfeitamente. Porém, gostaria de saber se tem como eu manipular este endereço que é enviado para a url.

Por exemplo (pesquisando para o Youtube):
Se o usuário digita "melhores seriados" no formulário, e pressiona Enter, o formulário completa o action com o name (q) e termo pesquisado e envia para a url.
Ficando: https://www.youtube.com/results**?q=melhores+seriados**

Além desta forma eu queria que ele mandasse a url sem o "name" e "?", apenas com "/" e o termo pesquisado, como se fosse um link normal.
Exemplo: https://www.youtube.com/results**/melhores+seriados**

Alguém sabe se tem alguma forma de manipular isso, com php ou javascript?

Segue o código do formulário:

```
<form name="searchfield" method="get" action="http://www.youtube.com/results" target="_blank">
<input type="text" id="input" name="q" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" size="36" placeholder="Pesquise no YouTube">
<input type="image" id="search" name="btnG" src="img/search.png">
</form>
```

Comment: Com relação ao "\" isso só vai funcionar se o site pro qual você está mandando aceitar URLs, amigáveis.

Comment: O outro site pra onde vc está enviando a pesquisa irá abrir em outra página?

Comment: Sim, abrirá em uma nova aba no navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes manipular a `action` do teu formulário no momento em que o mesmo é submetido:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.find('input[name="q"]').val(),
        url   = $this.attr('action');

    var newTargetUrl = (url+value).replace(" ", "+");

    $this.attr("action", newTargetUrl);

    // Para simular, comentar ou remover para ver a funcionar.
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(newTargetUrl);
});
```

Ver no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/1hd0uvtr/).

Mas com o YouTube, tens um problema, ele não apresenta resultados com URLs amigáveis pois não tem suporte para os mesmos.

Comment: Obrigado Zuul, faz sentido.
Vou testar aqui assim que possível. =D
Não conhecia essa questão das URLs amigáveis, caso não dê certo vou dar uma estudada nisso.